# lastInsertId() returns 0 even when placed after execute()

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This is my code:It returns 0 for last inserted id.I've referred to many samples online, they all say, lastInsertId must be called after execute() and before commit(). But in my code below, I don't use commit. Why its still returns 0?

```
try
{
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO usrinfo (UUID,Name,Phone,Email,Postcode,DateReg,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,Sex,Status,IsTuitionCentre) VALUES(:uuid,:name,:phone,:email,:poscode,now(),:reputation,:reviewplus,:reviewneg,:sex,:status,:permission)');
  $stmt2->execute(array(
    ':uuid' => $unique_id,
    ':name'=>$name,
    ':phone'=>$phone,
    ':email'=>$email,
    ':poscode'=>$postcode,
    ':reputation'=>78,
    ':reviewplus'=>65,
    ':reviewneg'=>3,
    ':sex'=>$gender,
    ':status'=>0,
    ':permission'=>$permission
  ));

   echo $lastinsertid = $pdo->lastInsertId();//returns 0
  # Affected Rows?
  echo $stmt2->rowCount(); // 1

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

EDITED:

Now I understood, `lastInsertId()` only works for AUTO_INCREMENT. And I realize that I could simply pass the $unique_id to ajax page! The problem now, I couldn't pass it.

I tried echo `$unique_id;`// but doesn't show the alert box

funnily, if I simply assign a value to a variable like below, it can pass through! WHy is it so?

```
echo $abc ="123";
```

AJAX:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
          $(".form").submit(function(){
            var data = {
              "action": "test"
            };
            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                //$(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data["json"] );
               // alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
               alert(data);
                // window.location='success.php'

              }
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
```

Comment: Last insert id only works when you declare an id with `AUTO_INCREMENT` and if you do not insert the id manually. So the problem is that.

Comment: So in order to solve that, do the following: 1) Make sure that the SQL definition for the `UUID` looks like this: `UUID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` 2) And remove the `:uuid' => $unique_id,` and let the id to be generated automatically

Comment: @bad_boy, thanks, now I know it only works with auto_increment..But i need to use unique Id for some reason..Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the problem anyway? With the approach I described above all ids will be unique anyway. For example, on first insert the id will be 1, on second 2, on third 3 and so on. Even if you remove a row with some id, mysql engine keeps the track anyway so the next id will be unique as well. So you'll get both unique ids and working `last_insert_id()`. That's what you're looking for, aren't you?

Comment: @bad_boy, that I know but I still need to create unique id. But the problem now is passing the unique id value to an ajax page. I thought I could get it using lastInsertId(0, luckily you told it only works for auto_increment so I stopped trying that out. In order to pass the value to ajax, I echoed $unique_id but it doesn't show alert box with that value. Funily when I pass $abc="123"; it does alert! This is my problem now!

Comment: You need to use unique id for some reason? Your code clearly states that you already have that in your `$unique_id` variable, what do you expect to get back from database? The same thing you gave it in the first place?

Comment: @N.B., please refer to the edited part above..

Comment: You don't need, you don't have to bother about generating **unique ids**. That will be done automatically by MySQL itself! Just declare `id` column, and don't mention it when running insert query. `last_insert_id()` will work!  Come on, it's really that simple!